# Tensorflow (keras) model gives me always the same value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

model.predict(x) where x is the same np array i used to train the model(x is obviously without the validation values).
Running this I just get the same value for all 1733 lines of numpy array. If you need code or an example for the np arrays used ask me.
the model is:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('BNB.csv')
x = dataset.drop(columns=["Valuable"])
x = np.asarray(x).astype('float32')
y = dataset["Valuable"]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape=x_train.shape, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000)
```

The numpy array (csv file) I used to train and test looks like this:

```
Valuable,Open,High,Low,Close,EMA8,EMA14,EMA50,ht,sar,MorningStar,Engulfing
-1,355.48,355.82,355.21,355.76,355.21,355.51,357.96,356.63,351.08,0,0
0,355.77,356.2,355.52,355.79,355.34,355.54,357.87,356.51,351.08,0,0
0,355.82,356.61,355.5,356.23,355.54,355.63,357.81,356.44,351.08,0,0
0,356.14,356.17,354.63,354.92,355.4,355.54,357.69,356.46,351.08,0,0
0,354.88,355.54,354.81,354.96,355.3,355.46,357.59,356.55,351.08,0,0
0,354.91,354.91,353.71,354.11,355.04,355.28,357.45,356.59,351.08,0,0
0,354.12,354.93,353.89,354.72,354.97,355.21,357.34,356.44,351.08,0,0
0,354.72,355.2,354.01,354.7,354.91,355.14,357.24,356.21,351.08,0,0
0,354.69,355.46,354.43,355.23,354.98,355.15,357.16,355.9,351.08,0,100
0,355.27,355.47,354.54,355.39,355.07,355.18,357.09,355.57,351.08,0,0
0,355.37,356.0,355.22,355.81,355.24,355.27,357.04,355.31,351.08,0,0
0,355.79,356.23,355.11,355.54,355.3,355.3,356.98,355.15,351.08,0,0
0,355.56,355.67,354.78,355.21,355.28,355.29,356.91,355.08,351.08,0,0
0,355.2,355.63,354.88,355.2,355.26,355.28,356.84,355.06,351.08,0,0
0,355.2,355.99,355.2,355.76,355.37,355.34,356.8,355.08,351.08,0,0
0,355.74,355.97,355.17,355.37,355.37,355.35,356.75,355.14,351.08,0,0
0,355.37,355.38,354.51,354.69,355.22,355.26,356.67,355.19,351.08,0,0
0,354.78,355.4,354.64,355.02,355.18,355.23,356.6,355.23,351.08,0,0
```

I want to predict whether Valuable is 0, -1, -2, 1 or 2 (my csv file is about 1700 lines long).

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing your model. You can look into `mode collapse` which is a problem for specific architectures like `Generative Adversarial Networks`.

Comment: You can see most of my code now

Comment: You only have one sample with the label `-1`? The labels should be in [`[0,1]`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy) and only works for binary (0 or 1) classification applications.

Comment: As I said my np array is way longer and I got all the labels in it somewhere. What can I use so my label can be more than just binary?

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your model.

**First:**
You should use sparse categorical cross entropy loss instead of binary loss for your model if you have more than two classes in output.

**Second:**
Use softmax activation for the last/output layer.

**Third:**
Use as many neurons in the last layer as there are classes.

Answer (score 0):

I consider the distinct values in `valuable` column are: `[-1,-2,0,1,2]`.

First encode your target column like this:

```
y = dataset["Valuable"] # after this

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(y)
```

Then Change your model definition like this:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

# changes
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape=x_train.shape, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5,   activation="softmax")) 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy']) 

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000)
```

Comment: Okay so now I get 5 values per row:
0.00786251 0.00799891 0.96776617 0.00948698 0.00688546
how can I say now if it is -1,-2,0,1 or 2

Comment: The 5 values always stay mostly the same (the third differs between 0.97 and 0.95)

Comment: Then use it like this: `y_pred = model.predict(x_test)` then `np.argmax(y_pred,axis=-1)-2`. This values `0.00786251 0.00799891 0.96776617 0.00948698 0.00688546` shows that it predicted the third class which is `0` with `0.96776617 ` probability.

Comment: okay well im running into the issue that every value of my np array gives me around 96% probability being 0. Have I trained it with to little examples or what exactly is the problem? Its like my first time ever doing something with ML.

Comment: When you train your model like this `model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data = (x_test,y_test), epochs=1000)` what is the `val_accuracy` and `val_loss` in the last epochs?

Comment: loss: 0.2024 - accuracy: 0.9642

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I believe
outside optimizer & cost function
you should consider also to Standardize the features

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
```